# How can I select unique values from several columns in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically, I've got the following table:

```
ID | Amount
AA | 10
AA | 20
BB | 30
BB | 40
CC | 10
CC | 50
DD | 20
DD | 60
EE | 30
EE | 70
```

I need to get unique entries in each column as in following example:

```
ID | Amount
AA | 10
BB | 30
CC | 50
DD | 60
EE | 70
```

So far following snippet gives almost what I wanted, but `first_value()` may return some value, which isn't unique in current column:

```
first_value(Amount) over (partition by ID)
```

`Distinct` also isn't helpful, as it returns unique rows, not its values

**EDIT:** 
Selection order doesn't matter

Comment: Do a GROUP BY on the ID column.

Comment: @jarlh And how would he display the `Amount`, based on the grouped `ID` values?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, good question, I can't see any pattern in how the selected values are chosen. Up to OP. (Or do you have any idea?)

Comment: @jarlh Not really, I don't see a pattern either. Sometimes looks like it's `min`, other times seems like it's `max`. I guess it is up to OP.

Comment: Is there any order in your data? For example, why would AA have 10 and not 20 in output? Maybe you can have better answers if you give some more details on your required output

Comment: @Aleksej I've made some edits before you commented: selection order doesn't matter

Comment: @Anton: so, to me there's no reason why result has AA-10 instead of AA-20. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Aleksej indeed there is no difference. I just made an example. It could be AA-20, BB-30, CC-50 etc. Or AA-20, BB-40, CC-10, EE-30 etc. As I said earlier, selection order doesn't matter here. It's just important to get unique values across columns. Essentially, unique values of this two-dimensional matrix

Comment: Individual columns must be unique so either AA 10 or AA 20 could be chosen as long as AA isn't already chosen and (10 or 20) haven't already been chosen. it's stated that selection order does not matter. (edit sorry was late hitting enter)

Comment: What if you only have AA 10 and  BB 10???

Comment: @parvij its not an option, I need distinct values in both columns

Comment: @Anton I mean what you expect as result when you just have two row: AA 10 and BB 10??? I got you need distinct values but what will happen if you have some row their value couldn't be distinct??? I know how you can solve your problem but this is a critical problem for every solution.

Comment: @parvij I cannot have only two row as I get my data from the feed, which contains always thousands of entries. So this case is out of scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, even with the problematic combinations mentioned by Dimitri. I don't know how fast that is for larger volumes though

```
with ids as (
  select id, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
  from data
  group by id
), amounts as (
  select amount, row_number() over (order by amount) as rn
  from data
  group by amount
)
select i.id, a.amount
from ids i
  join amounts a on i.rn = a.rn;
```

SQLFiddle currently doesn't work for me, here is my test script:

```
create table data (id varchar(10), amount integer);

insert into data values ('AA',10);
insert into data values ('AA',20);
insert into data values ('BB',30);
insert into data values ('BB',40);
insert into data values ('CC',10);
insert into data values ('CC',50);
insert into data values ('DD',20);
insert into data values ('DD',60);
insert into data values ('EE',30);
insert into data values ('EE',70);
```

Output:

```
id | amount
---+-------
AA |     10
BB |     20
CC |     30
DD |     40
EE |     50
```

Comment: The problem is easier if you can "break" the row. I mean, combination `EE 50` does not exists in the input data. The problem as it appears in the OP, is very dificult. It may not have solution for some inputs, it may have many solution for other inputs.

Comment: @FlorinGhita: ah, good point. I didn't understand it like that. I think the requirement "each value must be unique" can't be satisfied, if you aren't allowed to "break up" the rows.

Comment: However, I will vote this answer to bring the issue up. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using row_number() like this:

```
select ID ,Amount
from (
   select ID ,Amount, row_number() over(partition by id order by 1) as rn
   from yourtable
     )
where rn = 1
```

However your expected results don't conform to a discrenable order, some are the first/lowest while some the last/highest so I wasn't sure what to include for the ordering.

Comment: It didn't work properly unfortunately, I still get repeating values in `Amount` column. Thank you for your time

Comment: sorry, I missed the significance of those words, but now I understand what you need. mmmm

Answer (score 0):

My solution implements recursive `with` and makes following: first - select minival values of `ID` and `amount`, then for every next level searches values of `ID` and `amount`, which are more than already choosed (this provides uniqueness), and at the end query selects 1 row for every value of recursion level. But this is not an ultimate solution, because it is possible to find a combination of source data, where query will not work (I suppose, that such solution is impossible, at least in SQL).

```
with r (id, amount, lvl) as (select min(id), min(amount), 1
             from t
            union all
           select t.id, t.amount, r.lvl + 1
             from t, r
            where t.id > r.id and t.amount > r.amount)
select lvl, min(id), min(amount)
  from r
 group by lvl
 order by lvl
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69dbd3/1)

Comment: The same thing as in @Aleksej case: query time is extremely large and I simply cannot wait until it finishes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can solve:

```
WITH tx AS
     (  SELECT ROWNUM ROW_NUMBER,
               t.id,
               t.amount
          FROM test t
               INNER JOIN test t2
                   ON     t.id = t2.id
                      AND t.amount != t2.amount
      ORDER BY t.id)
SELECT tx1.id, tx1.amount
  FROM tx tx1
   LEFT JOIN tx tx2
       ON     tx1.id = tx2.id
          AND tx1.ROW_NUMBER > tx2.ROW_NUMBER
WHERE tx2.ROW_NUMBER IS NULL
```

Comment: I honestly tried to execute this query, but didn't manage as SQL Developer cannot finish query within even 5 minutes, which is too much. Thank you for your effort

Comment: `LEFT JOIN tx tx2 ON tx1.id = tx2.id(+)` looks terribly wrong. You should use **either** a proper `left join` **or** Oracle's proprietary `(+)` operator but not both in the same join condition.

Comment: ops.. my error. The operator (+) is wrong, just removed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I knew that there is an elegant solution! Thanks to friend of mine for a tip:

```
select max(ID), mAmount from (
  select ID, max(Amount) mAmount from table group by ID
)
group by mAmount;
```

Comment: It's elegant, but incorrect :) Try combination: `(BB, 30), (BB, 40), (CC, 30), (CC, 40)` My solution is the only solution, which gives correct answer with this combination (In fact, such combinations could be found for my solution too, but this solution is most weak).